# proof about orthogonal transformation in an inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a real inner product space of odd dimension and $S∈L(V,V)$ an orthogonal transformation. Prove that there is a vector $v$ such that $S^2(v)=v$.

Comment: Hint: Since $V$ has odd dimension, you know $S$ must have at least one real eigenvalue ...

Comment: You might also consider posting what work you have done so far and a bit of motivation for recent spree of linear algebra question.

Comment: Neal: and then?

Comment: "Then"? Then you're done! What are the possible eigenvalues of an orthonormal transformation? Ho are the possible eigenvalues of a power of *any* transformation related to the eignevalues of the transformation?

Comment: DonAntonio: I need more explanation here. What are the possible eigenvalues of an orthogonal transformation?

Comment: Actually I don't understand why $S$ must have at least one real eigenvalue ...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Orthogonal transformation in inner product spaces satisfies the following relation

$$ <u,v>=<Su,Sv> = <u,S^TS v> ,$$

and have the property $S=S^T$. Note that, $<u,v>=u^T \, v$.

Comment: Why $<Su,Sv>=<u,S^TSv>$,
and why  $S=S^T$?

Comment: @i_a_n: Check the inner product operations.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I get it. Can you explain them more clearly?